# Alternatives to slow self join (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, query-optimization, window-functions

I am self-joining a table in order to get, on the same row, the variable "status" at date t and at date t+1month, which are saved respectively as "status_a" and "status_b":

```
select * from 
  (select mydate, id, status status_a from T) A
inner join 
  (select add_months(mydate,1) mydate, id, status status_b from T) B 
using(mydate, id);
```

I do this since I need to check a condition that involves the value of the column "status" in the two adjacent periods, e.g. `status_a in(0,2,4) and status_b in(91,93,95)`.
The issue is that this join takes a lot of time, given the size of the table T.
Is there a way to do the same in a more efficient way?
Possibility that I considered:

1. Iterate the join over couples of dates rather than on the whole table T, which may require a PL/SQL statement.
2. It might be possible  to directly incorporate a simple condition in a window function; however since the conditions I need to check require to consider whether the values belong to lists of values (e.g. `status_a in(0,2,4) and status_b in(91,93,95)`), the output probably cannot be obtained with a window function. Additional complications arise if the two dates to consider for the condition are not adjacent nor 'first and last' record for each id.

Do you have any suggestion to speed up this self join, in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Your query has no mention of additional conditions on the statuses, so that part of the question is rather unclear.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  There is probably a simpler way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use window functions with a `range` specification. Your *existing query* could be rephrased as:

```
select
    mydate,
    id,
    status status_a,
    first_value(status) over(
        partition by id
        order by mydate
        range between interval '1' month preceding and interval '1' month preceding
    ) status_b
from t
```

If needed, additional conditions could be added directly within the window function, like:

```
first_value(case when status in (91,93,95) then status end) over(...)
```

But this cannot be assessed for sure without seeing an actual query that implements the logic you want, and/or sample data and desired results.